# s3 aws rm CLI recursive, rm delete bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

if i write

```
& aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/folder/ --recursive
```

it delete folder and it is ok, but if i write:

```
& aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/
```

does it delete bucket or not? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not. A bucket must be empty to delete it

Comment: what about data in bucket, does it delete folders and files?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to delete a bucket, you first have to delete all of the contents. If you're just looking to delete content (recursively) then do that. I'm having trouble understanding what you want to happen

Comment: it my mistake, i by chance typed this command : aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/ , and it started to do something ,and i saw in console delete: bucket/folder , and in few seconds i pressed control+C , and i don't know if it deleted something or not. I made research and actually data looks ok, but i have a lot of data, maybe it deleted something .

Answer (score 0):

use `aws s3 rb s3://my-bucket` to actually delete the bucket (only works when bucket is empty, or you can specify --force) -- note, that is `rb` as in remove bucket.

Answer (score -1):

alternatively, if your goal is to clean out a bucket and delete the bucket in it's entirety you can simply use --force

```
& aws s3 rm s3://my-bucket/ --region <region> --force
```

Comment: S3 does not use region. It also does not support a `--force` option.